# Line integral over a broken line

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a question about line integrals,

**Q**: Evaluate the line integral,

$$\int_C(2ye^{x^2-z}\cos(y^2)-9xy^2)dy+(12z-e^{x^2-z}\sin(y^2))dz+(2xe^{x^2-z}\sin(y^2)-3y^3)dx$$

Where C is the broken line from $A(0, \sqrt{\pi}, 3)$ to $B(0, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}, -1)$ connecting $(0, \sqrt{\pi}, 3)$, $(1,3,5)$, $(0,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}},-1)$.

I could solve this question if it was given a curve but I can't figure out how to solve this.

I tried to use the method on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538605/line-integration-over-a-broken-line) but I couldn't parametrize the lines.

How can I solve this question?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you solve this on each individual segment? You can parametrize a segment $AB$ using $P(t) = tA + (1-t)B$, where $t$ runs from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field is conservative with potential

$$f(x,y,z) = e^{x^2-z}\sin(y^2)-3xy^3+6z^2$$

Can you take it from here?